# Rows are represented as columns in a View

Tags: mysql

for my sense, I've a creative way of saving userdata. Let me explain:

I do not know which data is going to be saved in this database. For example, someone wants to save his icq number and i didn't know it before, where could he write it into? He dynamically creates a new field and in background there is an insert done in `fields` and an insert in user_fields where the new value of the new option is stored.

Table `user`:

```
id  username
1   rauchmelder
```

Table `fields`:

```
id  name
1   firstname
2   lastname
```

Table `user_fields`: (old values are stored as well as current, only youngest entry should be used)

```
id  user_id  fields_id  value        date
1   1        1          Chris        1.Mai
1   1        2          Rauch        1.Mai
1   1        1          Christopher  2.Mai
```

Result should be a View:

```
user.id  user.username   fields.firstname  fields.lastname
1        rauchmelder     Christopher       Rauch
```

Firstly, does it make sense at all?

Secondly, should I solve it in MySQL or within the application?

Thridly, how to solve this in MySQL as a View?

Comment: It sounds like what you're looking for is a join, but I'm having trouble following your dataset.

Comment: for every row in `fields` a column in the View will be created. From table `user_fields` the youngest/newest entry is selected for each "dynamically" created coulmn

Comment: It might help if you explain what you're trying to accomplish. That would make it easier for people to provide guidance.

Comment: Do you want to return the same fields for each user each time, or do you want the fields returned to vary dynamically depending on what is stored for that particular user? Here, you would only return firstname and lastname because that is all that is stored on `user_fields` for that user, but if another user also had icq number stored on `user_fields` then would you want to return that as well for that user? Also, are you able to vary the design to include a `latest_record` flag (for a given user_id and fields_id) on `user_fields`?

Comment: Oooh, a database in a database. That's rarely a good idea, and if you have to ask whether it is in your case it most certainly isn't.

Comment: Incidentally, you might be interested in this: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Entity%E2%80%93attribute%E2%80%93value_model

Comment: If the WHERE statement of a query shrinks the results to only users without icq, icq should not be mentioned, but if only one user would have an icq value this column should be shown. Of course you could add an latest_record row in table `fields` but what for?

Comment: Also, will you only be querying for one user at any given time, or will you ever want to return values for more than one user with a single query?

Comment: More than one user at a single time.

Comment: A latest_record flag in **`user_fields`** , not in `fields`. This is because in the question you said "only youngest entry should be used" - this requires an inefficient correlated sub-query in MySQL. (Other RDBMSs could use a relatively efficient window function to determine the latest entries dynamically, but these aren't available in MySQL.)

Comment: In which case, see bluefeet's answer. (With the latest_record flag, you could remove the join to the uf2 subquery and replace it with a simple `...where uf1.latest_flag=1` condition instead.)

Comment: Read some articles about EAV thanks for the hint!, There are various opinions. Would you prefer to solve this in the Database or is it faster i.e. in PHP?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In order to get the data into your columns, you can use an aggregate function with a `CASE` expression to convert the row data into columns.

If your `fields` are known ahead of time, then you can hard-code the values in your query:

```
select u.id,
  u.username,
  max(case when f.name = 'firstname' then uf.value end) firstname,
  max(case when f.name = 'lastname' then uf.value end) lastname
from user u
left join
(
  select uf1.*
  from user_fields uf1
  inner join
  (
    select max(date) maxDate, user_id, fields_id
    from user_fields
    group by user_id, fields_id
  ) uf2
    on uf1.date = uf2.maxdate
    and uf1.user_id = uf2.user_id
    and uf1.fields_id = uf2.fields_id
) uf
  on u.id = uf.user_id
left join fields f
  on uf.fields_id = f.id
group by u.id, u.username;
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/43822/8)

But since you are going to have unknown fields, then you will need to use a [prepared statement](http://buysql.com/mysql/14-how-to-automate-pivot-tables.html) to generate dynamic SQL to execute.  The syntax will be similar to this:

```
SET @sql = NULL;
SELECT
  GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT
    CONCAT(
      'max(CASE WHEN f.name = ''',
      name,
      ''' THEN uf.value END) AS `',
      name, '`'
    )
  ) INTO @sql
FROM fields;


SET @sql 
  = CONCAT('SELECT u.id,
            u.username, ', @sql, ' 
           from user u
           left join
           (
             select uf1.*
             from user_fields uf1
             inner join
             (
               select max(date) maxDate, user_id, fields_id
               from user_fields
               group by user_id, fields_id
             ) uf2
               on uf1.date = uf2.maxdate
               and uf1.user_id = uf2.user_id
               and uf1.fields_id = uf2.fields_id
           ) uf
             on u.id = uf.user_id
           left join fields f
             on uf.fields_id = f.id
           group by u.id, u.username');

PREPARE stmt FROM @sql;
EXECUTE stmt;
DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/43822/9)